# Why does typescript mark the property in a union as non existent?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Using TS 3.7.2 in strict mode, I have this type generated from graphql-codegen:

```js
type GetTopicFeedbacksCountQuery = { __typename?: 'Query' } & {
  topic: Maybe<
    | ({ __typename?: 'TopicModelAsMember' } & Pick<TopicModelAsMember, 'id'>)
    | ({ __typename?: 'TopicModelAsEditor' } & Pick<
        TopicModelAsEditor,
        'generateToken' | 'id'
      > & { feedbacksCount: TopicModelAsEditor['enrolmentsCount'] })
  >
}
```

and whenever I try to use it and I want to access `feedbacksCount` property I get this type error:

[image]

Now I know I can force TS the type like this to avoid type errors:

```js
const feedbacksCount = (topic as TopicModelAsEditor & {
                      feedbacksCount: TopicModelAsEditor['enrolmentsCount']
                    }).feedbacksCount
```

but isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a union could be one of several types, you should check the `__typename` property to determine what type you're working with using a switch or if statement:

```
function exampleUsage (query: GetTopicFeedbacksCountQuery) {
  if (query.topic.__typename === 'TopicModelAsEditor') {
    console.log(query.topic.feedbacksCount)
  }
}
```